# angular checkbox form with ng-repeat can only select one option

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-forms

I am trying to create a multistep form and step 2 is a bunch of checkboxes.  Here is the form with checkboxes:

```
<form ng-submit="createSubCategory(formData)">
    <div ng-repeat="sub_category in event_sub_categories">
        <ion-checkbox ng-model="formData.sub_category" ng-true-value="'{{sub_category}}'">
          {{sub_category}}</ion-checkbox>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">Continue</button>
</form>
```

The data for the checkboxes (`event_sub_categories`) is pulled from a server.  I need to save the inputs selected by the user to formData.  formData is being collected on each page of the multistep form and it will be submitted with a post request after all of the form pages.  I am new to angular and I am somewhat confused as to how check boxes work.

Question 1:  I understand how ng-model works with normal textfields.  But I'm not sure I get how it works with checkboxes.  Does ng-model replace the html name element?  Meaning, when I submit this to the server using `$resource`, are the keys of the data set by ng-model?

question 2: How can I name ng-model so that it is part of formData but so that it is also related to the name of `sub_category` being pulled from the database.  The problem is that with the code above, only one checkbox can be selected at any given time and I want the user to be able to check many checkboxes at a given time.  If it's not possible to do this, how can I get the functionality I need with checkboxes?

Comment: maybe something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/t7kr8/211/

Comment: Also, this is tagged with `ionic-framework` so i'm guessing you're using ionic. Have you looked at `ion-checkbox`? http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionCheckbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to select multiple checkboxes at once you need an object (angular) to hold all of the values. I have implemented this code in my own applications and find it fairly easy for the function receiving it to interpret the object. (iterate the object checking for true/false values)

Here is your `<ion-checkbox>` code:

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="sub_category in event_sub_categories" ng-model="formData[sub_category]">
```

This will set `subcategory: true/false` inside the `formData` object for every checkbox that is clicked.

Then all you need to do is send that `formData` object to where ever, the same way you were doing as before. Here is a codepen that displays the checkboxes changing, the updated `formData` object and the `formData` object stringified.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNdaev?editors=1010

**I have created my own values for `event_sub_categories` as an example, so of course these would be different from your own**

Comment if you have any questions.